# how to stop looping when json is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch

I have an API and it has pagination. but in jsonnya there is no total page data. so I made a script to get the page count. the script is like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                console.log(i + 1)
                hst = window.location.origin
                row = i + 1
                rl = hst + "/admin/all?page=" + row + "&limit=15"
                fetch(rl)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        // console.log(data.user_data)
                        if (i == 2) {
                            return
                        }
                    })
            }
        })
```

json

```
{
  "limit": 1,
  "page": 3,
  "user_data": [
    {
      "ID": 5,
      "CreatedAt": "2021-03-04T17:07:08+07:00",
      "UpdatedAt": "2021-03-04T17:07:08+07:00",
      "DeletedAt": null,
      "Email": "asdasd",
      "Password": "asdas",
      "Name": "asd",
      "UserRoleID": 1,
      "UserRole": {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Admin"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

then how to stop the for looping when the json "user data" is empty? like this

```
{
  "limit": 1,
  "page": 4,
  "user_data": [
    
  ]
}
``
```

Comment: You need to read up on how asynchronous events are handled. The browser does not wait for `.then()` to continue the for loop. You have to wait for each request to be completed and then get the new page if you want. The way you are doing it now is starting all 10000 requests at once.

Comment: `I have an API and it has pagination. but in json there is no total page data` - why are you trying to fix an obvious problem with the API on the front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you misunderstood the promise part of your code.

If you want to write it like that, you must use `async/await` syntax :

```
$(document).ready(async function () { //THERE
            for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                console.log(i + 1)
                hst = window.location.origin
                row = i + 1
                rl = hst + "/admin/all?page=" + row + "&limit=15"
                const resp = await fetch(rl); //we send the request
                const json = await resp.json(); //we get the response body as JSON
                if(json.user_data.length === 0) break;
                //json contains all your json content
          
            }
        })
   }
```

## Why ?

Because promises are asynchronus. When they will resolve, your forloop will be over for ages (at computer scale). `Promise.then()` will never block your thread and continue the execution.

So, if you loop on 10 elements, you will send 10 simultaneous request that will (or will not) resolve in some order (likely not the one you think) later.

There is more info about promises there, if you want : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

## Async/await

The `async/await` syntax is syntactic sugar : under the hood, you get Promises, but the syntax allow you to write your code in a way that **looks** synchronus. It's far easier to read AND to write, but you can do the same thing.

If we get your example again, you could write it like this (to get ride of `async/await` and use pure Promise syntaxe ) :

```
let row = 0;
function fetchThings(){
   if(row >= 10000) return;
   hst = window.location.origin
   row = i + 1
   rl = hst + "/admin/all?page=" + row + "&limit=15"
   fetch(rl).then(resp=>resp.json()).then((json)=>{
       if(json.user_data.length > 0) fetchThings();
   })
}

$(document).ready(fetchThings);
```

Comment: then how do you retrieve data from json using your method? sorry, I'm a little confused

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify it, but you get it in the `json` variable : First, you send the request with `const resp = await fetch(url);`. The `resp` variable is an object on wich you call `resp.json()` that returns a promise. So if you do `const jsonData = await resp.json()` : `jsonData` contains your json when the `resp.json()` promise resolve.

Take some times to read the link I provided in the answer, it will help you to understand how it works.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I used the first method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the length of your user data in your for loop. If it is 0, you can use a break statement to break from the for loop

```
for(let i=0;i<1000;i++){
   if(user_data.length===0){
     break 
  }
}
```